# How to create a count variable by group for specific values in the variable of interest?

Tags: r, count, sequence

At the moment I have to deal with paradata (long-format) generated by a software during the data collection phase of a cohort study.

How can I create a variable containing the number of occurence of a certain value by a group-variable (like `by id: gen _n if VAR1==2` in Stata)?

Basically the data looks like this:

```
 ID:   VAR1:    
 1       2      
 1       1      
 1       2      
 2       2      
 2       3      
 2       2      
 3       2      
 3       2      
 3       2
```

I can create a variable count.1 using

```
`data$count.1 <- ave(data$VAR1, data$ID,  FUN = seq_along)`

 ID:   VAR1:    count.1: 
 1       2       1           
 1       1       2           
 1       2       3          
 2       2       1            
 2       3       2           
 2       2       3            
 3       2       1            
 3       2       2            
 3       2       3
```

How can I create a variable count.2 counting by ID the number of the occurence of the event 2 in VAR1?

```
 ID:   VAR1:    count.1:  count.2:
 1       2       1            1
 1       1       2           NA
 1       2       3            2
 2       2       1            1
 2       3       2           NA
 2       2       3            2
 3       1       1           NA
 3       2       2            1
 3       2       3            2
```

The Data:

```
ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
VAR1=c(2,1,2,2,3,2,1,2,2)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, VAR1))
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You can create `data` by `data <- data.frame(ID, VAR1)`.  If there are `character` columns `as.data.frame(cbind(..` could create problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 data$count.2 <- with(data, ave(VAR1==2, ID,
                 FUN=function(x) ifelse(x, cumsum(x), NA)) )

 data$count.2
 #[1]  1 NA  2  1 NA  2 NA  1  2
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(data)[VAR1==2, count.2:=1:.N, by=ID][]
 #   ID VAR1 count.2
 #1:  1    2       1
 #2:  1    1      NA
 #3:  1    2       2
 #4:  2    2       1
 #5:  2    3      NA
 #6:  2    2       2
 #7:  3    1      NA
 #8:  3    2       1
 #9:  3    2       2
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 data %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(count.2= ifelse(VAR1==2, cumsum(VAR1==2), NA))
```